# Do Weblogic diagnostic watches run if the server is down?

Tags: weblogic

From what I can tell, the WebLogic watches (the ones that dont run as SNMP agents) get deployed on whatever weblogic server you want monitored. So if the WebLogic server is not up, they wont run will they?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. From [WebLogic documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13714/config_watch_notif.htm):

> You must associate a watch with a notification for a useful diagnostic activity to occur, for example, to notify an administrator about **specified states or activities in a running server**.

However, you may deploy your watches on Admin Server and monitor managed servers like in this blog article: [Are My Servers Running?](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/are_my_servers_running)

> #### Create a watch to detect inactive servers
>
> Now, we will create the watch rule. We will create a watch rule based on runtime mbean data. Specifically, we will use the State attribute on the ServerLifeCycleRuntimeMBean mbeans. **For each server within the domain, there is a ServerLifeCycleRuntimeMBean mbean in the domain runtime mbean server**. The State attribute reflects the current state of the server. We will configure a rule which will fire when at least one server in the domain is not in the RUNNING state.

As expected, these kind of watches would stop working if Admin Server is down.

Answer (score -1):

You're correct. It's not technically a deployment. You can look into 'Disabling Harvesting' if you prefer to avoid gathering the data even when the server is running.